# Using Kohana Routes to redirect

Tags: redirect, routes, kohana, kohana-3

I am using Kohana Framework 3.2

Usually in my bootstrap file, I can setup a Route::set like this:

```
Route::set('faq', 'faq')->defaults(array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'faq'));
```

This does so example.com/faq points to my controller home, action faq.

I would like to know if I can setup a redirection this way also?

So I can say that example.com/faq should redirect to example.com/thegreatfaqs?

Or must use route::set like the above, to a controller that **then** request redirects to /thegreatfaqs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in with Kohana to handle redirection within the routes.

What I typically do is route to a redirect controller which has all my redirect rules and I process the redirect there.

Comment: How would you do this exactly? Route to a redirect controller = that means you make a route that grabs everything (like the default route) and then from the controller you check with your rules if example /faq should be redirected to google.com/blabla ? What if its not and we need other routes aswell? Do you put the redirect route at the end of all other routes ?

Comment: yes it is the last route. In the case no redirect matches are found, you can throw a 404 exception or if you have some error controller/action you can just call that directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [`Route filter`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#route-filters), but I think this is a ***Bad Idea*** since you're interrupting the normal flow of a Kohana application.

```
Route::set('redirecturl', 'redirecturl')
->filter(function($route, $params, $request) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit;
});
```

I'd suggest a [Redirect rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) (Apache .htaccess) or a redirect from a dedicated controller action as mentioned by Scott is a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your route like this....>

```
Route::set('faq', 'thegreatfaqs(/<action>(/<id>))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller'    => 'home',
    'action'    => 'faq',
));
```

Comment: This points to a controller/action which I do not seek. I would like to setup a redirection so example.com/faq can point to whatever, it can be an external site like google.com/faq

Comment: okay.. the cleaner solution would be to implement as answered by Scott here.